# Clonar elemento HTML sem clonar evento

Tags: jquery

Possuo em meu `HTML` um form que utilizo para `"mock"` ou seja, ele só serve para ser `clonado` para outros lugares.

Após a primeira clonagem eu altero alguns inputs para que eles utilizem um plugin de `datetimepicker` porém após tentar clonar por uma segunda vez o `input` `datetimepicker` sempre referencia ao clone anterior.

```
$("#addPriceList").on('click', function () {
    $('.box-list-price-form').slideDown();

    let cloned = $('.list-price-form-mock').last().clone({
      withDataAndEvents: false,
    });

    /**
     * Adiciona o plugin de datetimepicker aos elementos clonados
     */
    $.map($(cloned).find('.datep'), function(element) {
      $(element).datetimepicker({
          format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
          locale: 'pt-BR'
      });
    });

    $(cloned).removeClass('is-hidden').appendTo('.price-forms form');
});
```

Ou seja, quando clono pela segunda vez o segundo input de `datetimepicker` esta apontando para o clone anterior, eu estou alterando o input do clone anterior ao invés do clone atual. Como faço para remover essa associação? já tentei `withDateAndEvents: false` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Não entendi a função do `$.map`. Apenas o `$(cloned).find('.datep')` já pega todos os elementos de uma vez.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui baseado no seu código e funcionou normal, ou seja, cada input clonado ficou com seu próprio datetimepicker.